# MySQL Error 1146: Table 'sys.campaign_view' doesn't exist and MySQL Error 1356

Tags: mysql

I've created a view called `campaign_view`.  The view is comprised of info spread across numerous tables (I use six joins).  When I try to add a seventh join, I get 'Error 1146: Table sys.campaign_view doesn't exist'.

I have tried restarting my server as suggested with no luck.
I have tried actually removing the view and recreating it.  I cannot recreate with the seventh join instruction without experiencing Error 1356.

I've tried using the reserved word FORCE to get around 1356, but that doesn't resolve the issue either.  I'm almost certain it's something easy that I'm missing.

Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is to add three new columns to the `campaign_view` view from another `account_stat_summaries` view.  There are six rows in `campaign_view` and three rows in `account_stat_summaries`. I want them paired based on the `account_key` which exists in both tables, and I would like to end up with a table that contains six rows; this should be a left join with the `campaign_view` being the left view/table.

One suggestion was that my left join is listed before the other joins (all inner joins be default), but that didn't fix it either.  Explicitly listing every join also didn't resolve the issue.

I've posted my code below which successfully created my table and the addition join that breaks everything.

Original Query (Successfully creates table)

```
CREATE 
VIEW `campaign_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `camp`.`campaign_key` AS `ad_id`,
        `a`.`modified` AS `modified`,
        `a`.`fname` AS `fname`,
        `a`.`lname` AS `lname`,
        `a`.`account_key` AS `account_table_key`,
        `s`.`status` AS `account_status`,
        `a`.`account_comment` AS `account_comment`,
        `a`.`platform` AS `platform`,
        `a`.`details` AS `details`,
        `a`.`account_claimed` AS `account_claimed`,
        `a`.`pixel` AS `pixel`,
        `a`.`angle` AS `angle`,
        `c`.`headline` AS `headline`,
        `c`.`body` AS `body`,
        `c`.`link_to_graphic` AS `link_to_graphic`,
        `su`.`url` AS `url`,
        `su`.`site_claimed` AS `site_claimed`,
        `camp`.`media_buyer` AS `media_buyer`,
        `camp`.`uploader` AS `uploader`,
        `a`.`created` AS `date_created`,
        `v`.`name` AS `vertical`,
        `camp`.`campaign_name` AS `campaign_name`,
        `ads`.`adset_key` AS `adset_key`,
        `ads`.`country` AS `country`
    FROM
        ((((((`accounts` `a`
        JOIN `campaigns` `camp` ON ((`camp`.`account_key` = `a`.`account_key`)))
        JOIN `adsets` `ads` ON ((`ads`.`campaign_key` = `camp`.`campaign_key`)))
        JOIN `content` `c` ON ((`c`.`adset_key` = `ads`.`adset_key`)))
        JOIN `status` `s` ON ((`a`.`status_key` = `s`.`status_key`)))
        JOIN `safe_urls` `su` ON ((`su`.`safe_url_key` = `a`.`safe_url_key`)))
        JOIN `verticals` `v` ON ((`v`.`vertical_key` = `a`.`vertical_key`)))
```

Addition That Breaks Everything

```
JOIN `account_stat_summaries` `ass` ON ((`a`.`account_key` = `ass`.`account_key`)))
```

I would be so grateful if someone could assist!

Comment: Get rid of all the unnecessary parentheses around the joins.

Comment: Can you run the same statement outside of the view?

Comment: Yes, running the same statement (without the extra parentheses) as just a SELECT statement returns the correct results. I can create a new table with a slightly different name successfully, but when I drop the old table and attempt to rename the slightly differently named table I see error 1356.  This is very odd.

Comment: Something is not right with the permissions around that `account_stat_summaries` table then.

Comment: account_stat_summaries is a VIEW.

I currently have DEFINER = \`root\`@\`localhost\` and am logged in as the root user though.  I also haven't messed with the permissions for the view.

Is this a problem because I'm trying to join a VIEW with TABLEs?

Comment: Actually, I think that the cause was a circular reference between the various VIEWs and TABLEs being utilized.

Hopefully this is useful for someone else out there who runs into a similar issue.